# getting a spike in dns queries every 3rd day

Tags: dns, spike

About a month ago a bought a domain name from an auction.
it has been all good but then about 10 days ago i started to noticed it was getting upto 200,000 dns queries every 3rd day, then would drop down to about 10,000 and spike again. And it is continuing to do this.

Would anyone know how i can see where these are coming from or stop them? At the moment i have nothing running on the domain, it just points to a coming soon page. I have the DNS with DNSmadeeasy.

[image: dns queries]

Comment: also i have analytics running on the coming soon page. and is not getting any visitors other then 1 or 2 a day. so it can't be from people going to the url.

Comment: directly ask dnsmadeeasy support. they are very helpful, gave me a log except for understanding a similar problem in the past.